# Scikit-learn vs. WEKA classification model implementation

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka

Am I correct to assume that the classification models implementations in scikit-learn and WEKA (e.g. Naive Bayes, Random Forest etc.) produce the same results (not taking processing time and such into account)?

I am asking, because I wrote my pipeline in Python and would like to use scikit-learn for easy integration. Since most related research and previous work in my field have used WEKA and Java, I was wondering if comparing performance to my pipeline is valid and scietifically sound, given I use the same models, settings, etc.